# Akka Java API artifactId versioning?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, akka, versioning

I am curious about Akka's Java API versioning conventions, and I can find nothing in their docs.

If you got to Maven repo and search for available `akka-actor` versions, you'll find entries like:

- `'com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.10:2.3.15'` or
- `'com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:2.4.4'`

**Question**: what is the significance of the `2.10` vs `2.11` qualifiers suffixing the `artifactId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the `artifactId` is encoding the Scala version distribution (2.10, 2.11) as also stated in [this old Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/ZSmcahfVD9U/discussion)

> we adopted the sbt standard of encoding the Scala binary version in the artifact name, i.e. the core actor package’s artifactId is “akka-actor_2.10” and “akka-actor_2.11”.

The post is from **Martynas Mickevicius**, part of the [akka team](http://akka.io/team).

The same is also mentioned in their official website as part of the [Release notes](http://akka.io/news/2014/04/09/akka-2.3.2-released.html) of the version **2.3.2**

> **Additional Release Details**
>   The artifacts comprising this release have been published to https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/ and also to Maven Central. In addition, we adopted the sbt standard of encoding the Scala binary version in the artifact name, i.e. the core actor package’s artifactId is “akka-actor_2.10”.

This is also clear when looking at its [releases history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akka_(toolkit)#Releases).

> **2.1.0**   Dec 22, 2012  part of Scala 2.10.x distribution > Mavdn dependency `com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.10:2.1.0`
>
> **2.3.2**   Apr 9, 2014   part of Scala 2.11.0 distribution > Maven dependency `com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:2.3.2`

Hence, for each akka-scala compatible version, then a further versioning is applied via the standard `version` element of the concerned dependency.